# Models are exported without texture

Tags: texturing

**#Context:**
I am trying to export a few objects with textures. These models will be used in CLO3D *(CLO is Marvelous Designer's bigger sister, used in the fashion industry instead of the movie/game industry)*.

**#Summary of the problem:**
When I add the models to CLO3D their textures are missing, even though the diffuse map shows up in CLO3D's UI but not in the viewport. I've tried OBJ, FBX, and GLB. [image: Screenshot of CLO3D]

**What I’ve tried:**

1. Packing external data:[image: external data is packed]
2. Baking all textures:[image: I baked all textures]
3. Export settings for FBX:[image: Tried to embed textures into FBX file]
4. Export settings for OBJ:[image: Export settings for OBJ]

I've been informed that the issue might not be on Blender's (settings) end, but on CLO's end, and while that may be true I am too tired and ignorant to know this for sure.
I will post this question on CLO3D and Marvelous Designer forums as well and once the problem is resolved, I will update this thread with the solution for others to find it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that ONE of the materials worked (mysteriously) and I really tried to figure out what set that one apart from others that didn't work. I looked and looked so hard I literally had to take a nap in between examinations because I couldn't find ANY difference.

Then, what I did was deleted all the materials that didn't export, duplicated the one that did, and replaced its maps (diffuse, roughness, and normal) with the maps I baked previously for the materials that failed to export.

From that point forward all models exported fine with textures.

So the problem was solved, but I haven't a single clue what the takeaway or lesson is.

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieve the image path

The image path must exist.
Otherwise, it does not seem to pack well into FBX data.

It may be a blender bug, but you may need to try once to see if the image path is correct.

Also, if the image is packed or if you are a faux user, the software may not be able to open the image.

In this case, you might try connecting the image directly to the shader by dragging and dropping it from your browser once. This method should solve most of the problems.

It may also be resolved by backing and unpacking once and then re-exporting the image.

### If there is a bug in the image

The bug also seems to depend on how the image is purified.
I have solved this problem by re-saving the image once baked with a different image software.

[image]
[image]

[image]